# Which version of ZooKeeper to use with Kafka 0.8.2.2?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

On the Kafka website they mention how LinkedIn is using ZooKeeper 3.3.4.

However, upon downloading the Kafka binary builds it's bundled with ZooKeeper 3.4.6; which version should I be using in production?

Comment: 3.4.6 is definitely a good choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the latest stable, as it's mostly bugfixes that they've addressed in the last few releases.  3.4.6 is definitely safe to use, and we have it in use across multiple production Kafka clusters.